# Include picture in top right, in the background of the rest of the document

Tags: graphics, positioning, backgrounds

I'm trying to recreate my CV with Latex, but currently struggle to include a picture of me in to top right, as it is usual.

I'm using [this template](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/europecv) and added

```
 \noindent \hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.5,clip]{picture.jpg}
```

where the document starts. Now everything is moved down, as the picture takes up space.

How can I include the graphic in the background, so the rest of the document is not affected?

Example: I have this on the left, I want to have it like on the right.

[image]

Comment: From the documentation: `\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-3.5cm}}`

Comment: ohmy. I should have seen that. Thank you! If you create an answer with that, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1):

As per design you display your picture either within the left frame or on right turn side. For displaying the pic on right turn side open the \ecvpicture{} in line 19 and compile.